# Django wrong current path in post request

Tags: python, django

When I try to login to admin page, after inserting credentials, I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://****/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Raised by:      django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='home']
^admin/
pdf/<slug:id>
report/<slug:id>

The current path, login/, didn't match any of these
```

As you can see, the current path Django is trying to match with pattern is "*login*" and not "*admin/login*"
When I try to load admin login page I'm not getting any error, so with a GET request it matches the right URL, so I think there is a problem with the current path in POST requests.
I'm hosting my website on A2hosting.
I never had this problem running in local.

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from form import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pdf/<slug:id>', views.generate_pdf),
    path('report/<slug:id>', views.report),
]
```

Comment: Can I see the error

Comment: The error I get it's in the post above

Comment: How does the `urls.py` looks like? It looks like you apprently wrote the include of the admin somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated the answer with my urls.py